# Is there any way to find why the following indexing error is occurring?

Tags: java, vector

I programmed a java code that has two vectors `v1` and `v2`. Now `v1` and `v2` both store data in a form of packet(assumed) which contains format like `v1.add("A",1,2)` or `v2("B",3,4)`, assume the packet size is 3. Now, v2 will check if its packet is already in v1. If it is there then `v2` will delete the packet and if it is not in `v1`, then the packet will be added to `v1` and will be deleted from `v2`. For example, `v1["A",1,2]` and `v2["A",1,1,"A",1,2]`.

Now, `v2` will start from `"A"`. It will find `A` in `v1`. Then it will go to `1`. Again, it will go to `1` and `v2` will not find `1` in `v1`. And it will add `("A",1,1)` to `v1` and delete it from `v2`. So `v1` stands `["A",1,2,"A",1,1]` and `v2` will stand with `["A",1,2]`. Now v2 will check again for if `["A",1,2]` is in `v1` or not. The program will start checking from the starting of `v1`. And it will find `"A"`, then `1`, then `2`. So `v2` will delete `["A",1,2]` from itself. Here is my code:

```
package privatechecker;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Vector;




public class Privatechecker {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=0,i=0,j=0,b=0,k=0;


     Vector v1= new Vector();
     Vector v2= new Vector();

     v1.add("A");
     v1.add(2);
     v1.add(3);

     v2.add("A");
     v2.add(2);
     v2.add(3);
     v2.add("B");
     v2.add(2);
     v2.add(3);
     v2.add("B");
     v2.add(2);
     v2.add(3);   
     v2.add("A");
     v2.add(7);
     v2.add(38);
     v2.add("C");
     v2.add(4);
     v2.add(5);
     v2.add("C");
     v2.add(10);
     v2.add(5);
     v2.add("C");
     v2.add(10);
     v2.add(5);
    do {
            for(j=0;j<v1.size()-1;){


               if(v2.get(i)== v1.get(j)){

                   i=i+1;
                   j=j+1;
                   a=0;

                   if(v2.get(i)== v1.get(j)){
                       i=i+1;
                       j=j+1;
                       a=0;
                       if(v2.get(i)== v1.get(j)){
                           System.out.println("Deleted "+v2.get(i));
                           v2.remove(i);
                           i=i-1;

                           System.out.println("Deleted "+v2.get(i));
                           v2.remove(i);
                           i=i-1;

                           System.out.println("Deleted "+v2.get(i));
                           v2.remove(i);
                           System.out.println("Buffered "+v2);

                           a=1;
                           i=0;
                           j=0;
                       }

                       else {

                           i=i-2;
                           j=j+1;
                           a=0;
                       }
                   }

                   else{


                       i=i-1;
                       j=j+2;
                       a=0;
                   }

               }

               else {

                   j=j+3;
                   i=0;
                   a=0;
               }
           }
           if(a==0){
               System.out.println("Added "+v2.get(i));
               v1.add(v2.get(i));
               v2.remove(0);


               System.out.println("Added "+v2.get(i));
               v1.add(v2.get(i));
               v2.remove(0);

               System.out.println("Added "+v2.get(i));
               v1.add(v2.get(i));
               v2.remove(0);


               System.out.println("Stored "+v1);
               System.out.println("Buffer "+v2);

               i=0;


    } 



           }
    while(v2.isEmpty()==false);

    System.out.println("Stored "+v1);
    System.out.println("Buffered "+v2);


    }


}
```

Now the problem is I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
    at privatechecker.Privatechecker.main(Privatechecker.java:53)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

I don't know why I am getting indexing error because I typed several print commands to check if the vector elements are getting correctly. They are all correct even v1 and v2 are having the exact elements I want. But as the errors are showing, I cannot get the vectors printed outside the loop. How to fix this ?

Comment: I suggest that rewording your problem statement may help viewers understand the problem and therefore help you with that. Would it be possible to explain what's the objective in plain English rather than explain the algorithm? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because the inner loop continues to iterate after v2 is empty.

Consider this excerpt of your code:

```
do {
    for(j=0;j<v1.size()-1;) {
       if(v2.get(i)== v1.get(j)) {
                   ...
}
while(v2.isEmpty()==false);
```

The `for` loop above iterates on v1. But the body of the code inside is removing entries from v2, which allows for the possibility for v2 to become empty before the loop is done iterating on v1.

The approach I used to find the issue:

1. The error message `Array index out of range: 0` indicated it was likely a get operating on an empty vector, since one would only get an out of range for an index of 0 if the vector was empty.
2. The error message included which line the error occurred on: `if(v2.get(i)== v1.get(j)) {`
3. Since there were two method calls that could have thrown the error, I tried those method calls on separate lines, to see which one was causing the error:

```
v2.get(i);
v1.get(j);
```

4. It turned out it was `v2.get(i)`, so I started looking for ways that v2 could be accessed after it was empty, and that's what led me to look at the for loop's exit conditions.

Depending on what your algorithm is designed to achieve, it could be a more complicated condition for the for loop is your way out or you may need to rethink your approach to the loops.

Comment: The problem was happening in the last 'if' inside the 'for' loop. After completing the task in third 'if', the program was jumping to the last 'else' inside the 'for' loop. I don't know why that was happening. Then inside the 'else', it changed the value of a from 1 to 0. Then it goes outside the for loop, performs the removing elements from v2 more than one time it is supposed to do. Now I put two break conditions to stop this. Now it's working